# Java Combo Box Not Filling from SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, combobox

In my Program I have a ComboBox in which the user can select the User he wishes to edit and currently the Class I use to fill the ComboBox is not doing it. I've look at some similar problems to this on the website but failed to see what I'm doing wrong. If someone can provide a fix to the problem it would be appreciated. I'm still quite new to most of this.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AdminPanelDelUser {


private String Host = "Hidden";
private String Name = "Hidden";
private String Pass = "Hidden";

private JComboBox<String> userPicker;
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AdminPanelDelUser window = new AdminPanelDelUser();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public AdminPanelDelUser() {
    initialize();
    getUserPicker();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 352);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JComboBox<String> userPicker = new JComboBox<String>();
    userPicker.setBounds(59, 6, 235, 27);
    frame.getContentPane().add(userPicker);
}

public JComboBox<String> getUserPicker() {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( Host, Name, Pass );  
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * From `table_1`");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            String name =rs.getString("user_name");
            userPicker.addItem(name);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        //Place Pop Warning Later
    }
    return userPicker;
}
}
```

Also any suggestions on how I can further improve the code would be happily taken. Thanks for anyone who helps me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating the `userPicker JComboBox` and assigning it to a variable with method level scope instead of using the variable with class level scope. The `JComboBox` you add to the content pane is different to the one you attempt to add items to (which incidentally is null when `getUserPicker()` is called).

```
JComboBox<String> userPicker = new JComboBox<String>();
```

should be

```
userPicker = new JComboBox<String>();
```

You might want to read http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html to get a better understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Change done in initialize function. The values are not setting because you are creating a new object userPicker. The following code is working

```
package com.mylender.test;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AdminPanelDelUser {



private JComboBox<String> userPicker;
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AdminPanelDelUser window = new AdminPanelDelUser();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public AdminPanelDelUser() {
    initialize();
    getUserPicker();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 352);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    //JComboBox<String> userPicker = new JComboBox<String>();
    userPicker = new JComboBox<String>();
    userPicker.setBounds(59, 6, 235, 27);
    frame.getContentPane().add(userPicker);
}

public void getUserPicker() {
    try {

        String a[]= {"HELLO","WORLD"};
        for(String s:a)
            userPicker.addItem(s);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        //Place Pop Warning Later
    }

}
}
```